# Scoring system xcode 5 sprite Kit

Tags: xcode, xcode5, sprite, scoring

I have an array of asteroids flying across the screen to the left towards my character. If they hit my character game over. If it doesn't hit my character and reaches to the end of the screen I want a score system to increment the score by one when this happens. I am using xcode 5. How can i achieve this. This code shows the movement of the asteroids

```
 double curTime = CACurrentMediaTime();
      if (curTime > _nextAsteroidSpawn) {
    //NSLog(@"spawning new asteroid");
    float randSecs = [self randomValueBetween:0.20 andValue:1.0];
    _nextAsteroidSpawn = randSecs + curTime;

    float randY = [self randomValueBetween:0.0 andValue:self.frame.size.height];
    float randDuration = [self randomValueBetween:2.0 andValue:10.0];

    SKSpriteNode *asteroid = [_asteroids objectAtIndex:_nextAsteroid];
    _nextAsteroid++;

    if (_nextAsteroid >= _asteroids.count) {
        _nextAsteroid = 0;
    }

    [asteroid removeAllActions];
    asteroid.position = CGPointMake(self.frame.size.width+asteroid.size.width/2, randY);
    asteroid.hidden = NO;

    CGPoint location = CGPointMake(-self.frame.size.width-asteroid.size.width, randY);

    SKAction *moveAction = [SKAction moveTo:location duration:randDuration];
    SKAction *doneAction = [SKAction runBlock:(dispatch_block_t)^() {
        //NSLog(@"Animation Completed");
        asteroid.hidden = YES;

    }];

    SKAction *moveAsteroidActionWithDone = [SKAction sequence:@[moveAction, doneAction ]];
    [asteroid runAction:moveAsteroidActionWithDone withKey:@"asteroidMoving"];
```

Answer (score 0):

Just change your done action completion block:

```
SKAction *doneAction = [SKAction runBlock:(dispatch_block_t)^() {
    //NSLog(@"Animation Completed");
    asteroid.hidden = YES;
    ++myAwesomeScore;
}];
```

I can't see how you're destroying the asteroids when they collide with the player, but if you're just hiding them and not completely deleting them (and therefore still hitting that `runBlock`. Then just modify it to something along the lines of:

```
SKAction *doneAction = [SKAction runBlock:(dispatch_block_t)^() {
    //NSLog(@"Animation Completed");
    asteroid.hidden = YES;
    if (asteroid.isNotDead) ++myAwesomeScore;
}];
```

Comment: Thank you but, I want to delete the Asteroids Like you suggested when they reach the end of the scene on the left, and when that happens increment the score